# Raspberry Pi Raspbian Web Kiosk Virtual Keyboard Solution

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen

I followed [Alan D. Moore's step-by-step guide](http://www.alandmoore.com/blog/2011/11/05/creating-a-kiosk-with-linux-and-x11-2011-edition/) to have my Raspberry Pi running in kiosk mode.

I did my own configuration as I needed it to run on a touchscreen with no physical keyboard and mouse.

Here's how my ~/.xinitrc file looks.

```
xset s off
xset -dpms
matchbox-window-manager &
matchbox-keyboard &
while true; do
    rsync -qr --delete --exclude='.Xauthority' /opt/kiosk/ $HOME/
    midori -i 600 -e Fullscreen -e Navigationbar -a http://myport.ac.uk
done
```

I used apt-get install for the matchbox-keyboard to be used as an on-screen virtual keyboard solution.

Just look at how small the keys are! Barely touchable and super inaccurate... [image: example]

The real question is if anyone knows of a way to make the keyboard bigger, could recommend other solutions or tweak the config? I am a total debian newbie so I really hope I get some help here. :)

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `--font-size` and `--geometry` UI options for `matchbox-keyboard` command?

Comment: @emcconville matchbox-keyboard --font-size --geometry & ? I can't seem to find any documentation on this (or I don't know where to look).

Comment: Apologies. I was referencing [Matchbox 1.5 fork](https://github.com/Xlab/matchbox-keyboard#matchbox-keyboard-15-fork). Original [matchbox-keyboard](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/matchbox-keyboard/tree/src/matchbox-keyboard.c#n38) should support a few UI options, like font-point size & column/row spacing

Comment: I tried them but I'm not very confident about my execution of the solution. What I did was just add --fontptsize 30 & to the above code but this time the keyboard doesn't even appear... I think I'm doing something wrong with the code. Any ideas?

Comment: Any progress? We're trying to clean up the site and this question hasn't been touched for a while...@emcconville Have you anything to add?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reduce the resolution of your screen for X or for RPI overall to something smaller, ie 1024x768 or similar, based on connected monitor aspect ratio.

Typically in linux you can do it in X-server(xorg.conf) settings, but for RPI just edit /boot/config.txt to force a specific video mode, ie:

```
# Set monitor resolution to 1024x768 XGA 60Hz (HDMI_DMT_XGA_60)
hdmi_mode=16
```

All modes (including non-HDMI) are listed here for your reference: http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to control where matchbox-keyboard shows using the `--geometry` argument. [This page](https://github.com/Xlab/matchbox-keyboard) suggests that the appropriate call would be something like this:

matchbox-keyboard --geometry HxW.y.x

x and y are the on-screen coordinates of the top-left corner of the keyboard window (from the top left corner of the screen), and W and H are the width and height of the keyboard.

There's an application called [devilspie2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/) that lets you mess around with where windows go when the application is first launched if they don't support the --geometry command line argument (that's most applications).

What you need to do is first install:

```
sudo apt-get install devilspie2
```

And then add it to the .xinitrc file so that it starts when X does:

```
matchbox-window-manager &
devilspie2 &
matchbox-keyboard &
```

Finally, you need to configure devilspie2 so that it knows what to do about matchbox-keyboard. You need to edit `~/.config/devilspie2/keyboard.lua`:

```
if (get_window_name() == "matchbox-keyboard") then
    set_window_geometry(x,y,W,H)
end
```

x,y,W,H are the same as above. Assuming 1920x1080, I'd suggest something like 0,600,1920,480.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making a web app, how about javascript virtual keyboard, or sometimes called on screen keyboard, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762431/js-based-on-screen-keyboard-for-browser-like-on-cellphones-and-tablets)

Answer (score 0):

matchbox is a very primitive virtual keyboard. If you're open to other options I recommend checking out [Onboard](https://launchpad.net/onboard) which makes theming & customization much easier. On raspbian you will also need the `at-spi2-core` module